# Как убрать вертикальные отступы у ImageView

Tags: android, android-studio

Использую DrawerLayout. В drawerAdapter для получения картинки без итема делаю для итема `LinearLayout.INVISIBLE`.

Не понятно откуда берутся большие вертикальные отступы у ImageView. Если фиксированно задать высоту например 100dp, то imageView становится нужного размера, но тогда в других итемах она хоть и `INVISBLE`, но место под нее (100dp) все равно остается и получаются отступы между итемами 100dp.

Картинка png 600x300. Но так происходит с любой картинкой любого размера.

[image]

**drawer_item.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/drawer_logo_layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:layout_margin="0dp"
   android:paddingStart="5dp"
   android:paddingEnd="5dp"
   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
   android:background="@color/background">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_logo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_item_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_item_icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/drawer_image"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />


 <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/drawer_item_name" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp">
 </TextView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: для `ImageView` добавьте параметр `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` - размер виджета по размеру картинки (по умолчанию размер виджета - квадрат, со стороной, равной большей стороне картинки)

Comment: @pavlofff, Спасибо